Import a surveyJS custom theme in svelte code
Morning,
Since yesterday, I have been trying to add a custom theme by following the information given on the surveyJS site.
I'm developing a site with svelte, I managed to import the form, but it's impossible to integrate the custom theme correctly :/
Anyone know where my mistake is?
import "survey-knockout/modern.min.css";


onMount(async () => {
    const {Survey} = await import ('survey-knockout');

    
    const survey = new Survey({surveyId: 'ID'})
    survey.applyTheme({
        "themeName": "flat",
        "colorPalette": "light",
        "isPanelless": false,
        "backgroundImage": "",
        "backgroundOpacity": 1,
        "backgroundImageAttachment": "scroll",
        "backgroundImageFit": "cover",
        "cssVariables": {
            "--sjs-questionpanel-hovercolor": "rgba(248, 248, 248, 1)",
            "--sjs-corner-radius": "4px",
            "--sjs-base-unit": "8px",
            "--sjs-shadow-small": "0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            "--sjs-shadow-inner": "inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-border-default": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
            "--sjs-border-light": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
            "--sjs-general-backcolor": "rgba(246, 246, 246, 1)",
            "--sjs-general-backcolor-dark": "rgba(235, 235, 235, 1)",
            "--sjs-general-backcolor-dim-light": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-general-backcolor-dim-dark": "rgba(235, 235, 235, 1)",
            "--sjs-general-forecolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91)",
            "--sjs-general-forecolor-light": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)",
            "--sjs-general-dim-forecolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91)",
            "--sjs-general-dim-forecolor-light": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)",
            "--sjs-secondary-backcolor": "rgba(255, 152, 20, 1)",
            "--sjs-secondary-backcolor-light": "rgba(255, 152, 20, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-secondary-backcolor-semi-light": "rgba(255, 152, 20, 0.25)",
            "--sjs-secondary-forecolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-secondary-forecolor-light": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)",
            "--sjs-shadow-small-reset": "0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            "--sjs-shadow-medium": "0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-shadow-large": "0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-shadow-inner-reset": "inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-border-inside": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)",
            "--sjs-special-red-forecolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-special-green": "rgba(25, 179, 148, 1)",
            "--sjs-special-green-light": "rgba(25, 179, 148, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-special-green-forecolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-special-blue": "rgba(67, 127, 217, 1)",
            "--sjs-special-blue-light": "rgba(67, 127, 217, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-special-blue-forecolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-special-yellow": "rgba(255, 152, 20, 1)",
            "--sjs-special-yellow-light": "rgba(255, 152, 20, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-special-yellow-forecolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-textDecoration": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-fontWeight": "700",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-fontStyle": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-fontStretch": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-letterSpacing": "0",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-lineHeight": "64px",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-paragraphIndent": "0px",
            "--sjs-article-font-xx-large-textCase": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-textDecoration": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-fontWeight": "700",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-fontStyle": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-fontStretch": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-letterSpacing": "0",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-lineHeight": "56px",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-paragraphIndent": "0px",
            "--sjs-article-font-x-large-textCase": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-textDecoration": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-fontWeight": "700",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-fontStyle": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-fontStretch": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-letterSpacing": "0",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-lineHeight": "40px",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-paragraphIndent": "0px",
            "--sjs-article-font-large-textCase": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-textDecoration": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-fontWeight": "700",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-fontStyle": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-fontStretch": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-letterSpacing": "0",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-lineHeight": "32px",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-paragraphIndent": "0px",
            "--sjs-article-font-medium-textCase": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-textDecoration": "none",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-fontWeight": "400",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-fontStyle": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-fontStretch": "normal",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-letterSpacing": "0",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-lineHeight": "28px",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-paragraphIndent": "0px",
            "--sjs-article-font-default-textCase": "none",
            "--sjs-general-backcolor-dim": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-primary-backcolor": "rgba(34, 35, 94, 1)",
            "--sjs-primary-backcolor-dark": "rgba(26, 27, 72, 1)",
            "--sjs-primary-backcolor-light": "rgba(34, 35, 94, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-primary-forecolor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
            "--sjs-primary-forecolor-light": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)",
            "--sjs-special-red": "rgba(229, 10, 62, 1)",
            "--sjs-special-red-light": "rgba(229, 10, 62, 0.1)",
            "--sjs-header-backcolor": "transparent"
        },
        "headerView": "basic"
    })
    survey.render(domNode)

})

The default themes work but not the custom :/

I've added your code in a simple Svelte app using SurveyJS. The result is here in StackBlitz
The custom theme is applied and works. I hope this helps you to get it working on your side.
In case it doesn't, I can investigate further but having only the import and onMount part of your code without the survey JSON, minimizes the chance to reproduce the problem and dig further.
Providing the entire code of the file and any additional context or a StackBlitz link where the custom theme fails to work, would be very helpful.
Any errors from the console could also bring some insight.
